# Vectorize nested for-loop and if statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, vectorization

i'm trying to vectorize the following nested loop, so I don't have to plot the values in a loop:

```
for i=1:size(validMaskX,1)
   for j=1:size(validMaskX,2)
      if( validMaskX(i,j) )
         plot(ah, [dataX(i,j) dataX(i,j+1)], [dataY(i,j) dataY(i,j+1)], 'g-')               
      end
    end
 end
```

- size(validMaskX) = 45x44
- size(dataX)=size(dataY)=45x45

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Not tested, but does `vind=find(validMaskX); vindn = vind + size(validMaskX, 1); plot(ah, [dataX(vind), dataX(vindn)], [dataY(vind), dataY(vindn)] );` work? That's assuming `validMaskX` and `dataX` and `dataY` have the same number of rows.

Comment: Do you want all the lines on the same axis? Because your code plots one line at a time, you'll need a loop for the time term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
vind=find(validMaskX);
vindn = vind + size(validMaskX, 1);
```

you can find the valid points and the second indices. Then, you can plot with

```
plot(ah, [dataX(vind), dataX(vindn)], [dataY(vind), dataY(vindn)], 'g-');
```

If you want only one plot object (which would make rendering much faster), consider

```
dx = [dataX(vind), dataX(vindn), nan(numel(vind), 1)]';
dy = [dataY(vind), dataY(vindn), nan(numel(vind), 1)]';
plot(ah, dx(:), dy(:), 'g-');
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: At least you changed the variables names... :)

Comment: Hey, I posted this as a comment way before you!

Comment: But then again, this is pretty standard stuff :)

Comment: Hi zeeMokeez,
I thought I understood your solution yesterday, but apparently I don't, because when I try to modify the following code, which is more or less the same, as the question I posted yesterday, it dosen't work:

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? The code itself? Or that you get other result than what you expected?

Comment: @K.Grouleff can you elaborate on your issue?

Comment: @zeeMokeez - I can run the code, but the result, is not what I expected, and what I get when I run the for-loop. I have made some comments longer down this page, about the issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the lines together on the figure, you can do that:

```
ind=find(validMask);
X=[dataX(ind) dataX(ind+45) nan(length(ind),1)];
Y=[dataY(ind) dataY(ind+45) nan(length(ind),1)];
plot(ah,X',Y','g-')
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I understood your solution yesterday, but apparently I don't, because when I try to modify the following code according to your answer, it dosen't work: How would you modify this according to your former answer?

```
for i=1:size(validMaskY,1)
   for j=1:size(validMaskY,2)
      if( validMaskY(i,j) )
      plot(ah, [dataX(i,j) dataX(i+1,j)], [dataY(i,j) dataY(i+1,j)], 'r-')
      end
   end
end
```

size(dataX)=size(dataY)

Comment: Try to change this line: `vindn = vind + 1;`

Comment: A. `size(validMaskY,1)` is 45, so when `i=45` you can not get `dataX(i+1,j)`, it will exceed matrix dimensions.  B. It will be much helpful if you can explain what exactly the problem. We can't guess what "your problem" is, and why it didn't solve.

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit more: When I try to vectorize the double for loop, I don't get the same figure, as when I run the double for-loop (which is the correct one!). The first question I posted, draw's connects lines between dots in one direction, and the latest post from me draw lines perpendicular to the other lines. The result is a grid where all dots that satisfy validMaskX, validMaskY is connected.
I can draw the lines in one direction, but not in the other direction.

Comment: I'm looping through a lot of images, so the size of dataX and dataY will vary, but will always equal each other. Size(validMaskX)=[m,n] where size(validMaskY)=[n,m], hope this helps

Comment: The original solution hinged on the fact that matrices are indexed in column-major order. @Adiel's comment regarding `vindn = vind + 1;` should work. Are the differences in your sizes for `validMaskX` and `validMaskY` correct?

Comment: If `[r, c] == size(dataX)` then `size(validMaskY)` should be `[r-1, c]` and `size(validMaskX)` should be `[r, c-1]`. Also make sure that for your second problem you use `dx = [dataX(vindn), dataX(vind), nan(numel(vind), 1)]';
dy = [dataY(vindn), dataY(vind), nan(numel(vind), 1)]';`

Comment: So I checked the following: 
[r,c]=size(dataX)=size(dataY)
[r,c-1]=size(validMaskX)
[r-1,c]=size(validMaskY)

But my plot is still not right, compared to the for-loop version.

Comment: Maybe attach some figures...?